# Polynomials $P(x)$ such that $P(x-1)$ $=$ $P(-x)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Are there an infinite number of polynomials $P(x)$ of even degree such that

$P(x-1) = P(-x)$

$P(x) = x^2+x+1$ is a good example because $P(x-1) = (x-1)^2+(x-1)+1 = x^2-x+1 = P(-x)$.

$P(x) = x^4+2x^3+4x^2+3x+1$ is another example because $P(x-1) = (x-1)^4+2(x-1)^3+4(x-1)^2+3(x-1)+1 = x^4-2x^3+4x^2-3x+1 = P(-x)$.

Is there an easy way to generate such polynomials? Thanks for help.

Comment: Once you have one example then $aP(x)$, $P(x)^2$ etc. will provide plenty more!

Answer (score 5):

The condition $P(-x)=P(x-1)$ is equivalent to $P(x-1/2)=P(-1/2-x)$,
namely that $P(x-1/2)$ is an even function. That should be helpful.

Comment: @dxiv it should!

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to generate infinitely many such polynomials is to start with your example $P(x)=x^2+x+1$ and consider $P(x)^2,P(x)^3,P(x)^4,\dots$